# how making a selection from a taxonomy selector fixed definitively

Tags: metabox

I have created a taxonomy “Ospiti” (guests) and set a selector in order to write the number of guests. If I select the number “7” and then edit the post , I see in the posts admin colum the n “7” correctly in correspondence of that post (apartment), but if I want to edit again that post the selector has lost the selection (I see it on 2 and not on 7). Pic of the selector: https://ibb.co/9wtqcdr
I write here the code I used for the creation of the metabox, someone can fix this error?

```php
function custom_meta_box_markup($object)
{
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");
    ?>
    <div>
      
        <label for="meta-box-ospiti">N.ospiti</label>
        <?php
        $selected_terms = wp_get_post_terms($object->ID, 'numero_ospiti', array('fields' => 'ids'));
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'numero_ospiti',
            'selected' => $selected_terms,
            'name' => 'tax_input[numero_ospiti][]',
            'hide_empty' => false
        );
        wp_dropdown_categories($args);
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function add_custom_meta_box()
{
     add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Ospiti", "custom_meta_box_markup",
"post", "side", "high", null);
}

add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **wp_dropdown_categories** function provides the HTML for a list of taxonomy terms based on the values assigned to its [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/#parameters). That is all it does. When users select a value from the taxonomy selector, the selected value is not saved to the database unless the developer saves it. As the developer, you need to decide to save it, and where it should be saved. A function that saves the selected value to the database is missing from your code.

When the user submits the form, the taxonomy selector value can be saved as a post meta value.

In your code, `$selected_terms` gets its value(s) from [wp_get_post_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/). **wp_get_post_terms** finds the taxonomy terms for the current post, not the last option selected from the taxonomy selector.

So, the code needs to 1. **display the form**; and 2. **save the value(s)** from the form.

### Display the form

The WordPress documentation for [wp_dropdown_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) indicates the data type for the `selected` parameter is `int|string`. Your code assigns `$selected_terms` which is an array. If multiple selected options are allowed the [wp_category_checklist](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_category_checklist/) function should be used. The code below assumes that multiple selected options are not allowed. Only a single option can be selected.

### Remove default meta boxes

See [remove_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/) in the WordPress documentation.

```
/**
 * Prevent the large meta boxes from appearing in the main
 * area of the Edit Post page.
 */
function remove_custom_meta_forms() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postcustom', 'post', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'postcustom', 'page', 'normal' );
    // remove_meta_box( 'postcustom', 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE', 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_custom_meta_forms' );
```

### Register post meta data field for use with REST API (optional)

If you are using a custom post type, update the **object_subtype** property.

```
/**
 * Register tax_input[numero_ospiti] field if you want it
 * to be available via WordPress REST API.
 */
function register_tax_input_ospiti() {
    \register_meta(
        'post',
        'tax_input[numero_ospiti]',
        array(
            'object_subtype'    => 'post',
            'description'       => 'Count of guests.',
            'single'            => true,
            'type'              => 'integer',
            'show_in_rest'      => array(
                'schema' => array(
                    'type'  => 'integer'
                )
            ),
            'default'           => 0,
            'sanitize_callback' => function( $value ) { return $value; },
            'auth_callback'     => function() { return '__return_true'; }
        )
    );
}
```

### Display taxonomy selector

```
function custom_meta_box_markup( $post ) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    // tax_input[numero_ospiti] is an array,
    // but managed as a single value.
    $is_single_value = true;

    // Retrieve the term name that was saved to the database.
    $selected_term_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'tax_input[numero_ospiti]', $is_single_value );
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'numero_ospiti',
        'fields'   => 'id=>name',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'number'   => 0
    ) );

    $flipped_terms = array_flip( $terms );
    if ( isset( $flipped_terms[ $selected_term_name ] ) ) {
        $selected_term_id = $flipped_terms[ $selected_term_name ];
    } else {
        $selected_term_id = 0;
    }

    $set_referer_field = true;
    $echo_html = false;
    $wp_nonce_html = wp_nonce_field(
        basename( __FILE__ ),
        'meta-box-nonce',
        $set_referer_field,
        $echo_html
    );

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'numero_ospiti',
        'selected'   => $selected_term_id,
        'name'       => 'tax_input[numero_ospiti]',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'echo'       => false
    );
    $dropdown_cat_html = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );

    $html = <<<EOHTML
    <div>
        $wp_nonce_html
        <label for="meta-box-ospiti">N.ospiti</label>
        $dropdown_cat_html
    </div>
    EOHTML;

    echo $html;
}

function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'demo-meta-box',          // Unique ID.
        'Ospiti',                 // Meta box title.
        'custom_meta_box_markup', // Content callback, must be of type callable.
        'post',                   // Screen type.
        'side'                    // Context: where meta box should display in the screen.
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box' );
```

### Save value(s) from the form to database

```
/**
 * Update post meta data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID of post being saved.
 */
function save_custom_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    if (
        isset( $_POST ) &&
        isset( $_POST['tax_input'] ) &&
        isset( $_POST['tax_input']['numero_ospiti'] )
    ) {
        $term_id = $_POST['tax_input']['numero_ospiti'];
        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'numero_ospiti',
            'fields'     => 'id=>name',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'number'     => 0
           ) );
        $selected_term_name = $terms[ $term_id  ];

        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            'tax_input[numero_ospiti]',
             $selected_term_name
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_meta_box' );
```

Comment: Hi, the code works correcly, I would need just 2 more parameters to avoid "collateral effects". The first is that I see in all the post edit pages the tax_imput function and its value: https://ibb.co/2qPD4ZT , the 2nd "collateral effect" is that now I cant see the number of guests in the column "ospiti" in the admin post table page: https://ibb.co/55KZ4ZY, that you in advance for your help!

Comment: You might have noticed that my answer changed the variable name from **tax_input[numero_ospiti][]** (an array) to **tax_input** (an integer [sent as a string by the form]). It was not clear to me why an array was used when your question said the taxonomy selector is *in order to write the number of guests*. I'm guessing that the "number of guests" is not what the user is choosing with the taxonomy selector. The user is choosing a taxonomy term. And, the chosen taxonomy term determines the number of guests by counting the number of posts that have that taxonomy term. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Maybe the taxonomy selector field name should be an array? Should your meta box allow users to select multiple options in the taxonomy selector? I need to know how the value of the taxonomy selector should be saved. It looks like the taxonomy term(s) need to be stored in a specific way for the guests to be counted correctly. Should the selected taxonomy term(s) be stored as a single integer in Post Meta (see [add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/) where **$unique** is true)? Or stored as an array (see **add_post_meta** where **$unique** is false)?

Comment: About the first "collateral effect": Are you seeing the taxonomy selector twice on the Edit Post page? Once as a single-select drop-down form field in the right-side column, and a second time as a text area form field (like in your image)? When I tested the taxonomy selector in my WordPress, I only see it in the right side column as a single-select drop-down form field (its position can be manually changed by the user to display in the default location in the main post edit area like your image). Would you know if your plugin is automatically creating a second meta box?

Comment: Hi, the selector is done specially to select the number of guests. I use it as administrator each time I insert a new apartment (normal post is used to manage apartments), I set also the max number of guests for this apartment. If they are 5 I select 5. Number 5 should be seen also in the admin post table in the colunm "ospiti" (guests).In the future there will be a search box on my site (public) which will also include the taxonomies, i.e. the user will be able to select an apartment also according to the maximum number of guests.

Comment: This is what I see in my edit post page: [link] ( https://ibb.co/GkMhn4n) ,first of all the position should be "side", and it's not "side", but this is not a great problem. The most relevant matter is the I see in a fixed way the fields "Tax_imput" and his value "269", which are not usefull to me, and also from a conceptual point of view it is incorrect because the taxonomy value does not end up in the admin post table column

Comment: @Andrea Sacconi I have updated my answer. You can see my changes by clicking the [Timeline](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/415714/timeline) icon at the top-left of my answer. You will need to test the code, and if it does not work, try to update it until it works. I have no information about which database tables should be updated. I do not know what the meta_keys should look like. And, I do not understand Italian. :-) I think the code I provided should give you a good start to finding a solution. If the code works please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I mark now as aswered but I still have the big problem to see my selection in the admin post table as a taxonomy value; speaking  about a specific post, I selected 5 in the taxonomy selector but I see 269 in the tax_input[numero_ospiti] function in the edit post page, so that in my admin post table I read 269, not 5. Taxonomy shouldnt be converted in a custom field, anyway thank you for your effort

Comment: I might be able to help further if you can provide details about how the data should be stored. Also, did you write the code that displays ospiti on the Admin List page, or is the code from a plugin? If you did it yourself it should be easy to help you display the correct data. Currently, it looks like the term_id is being displayed. I'm assuming the you configured the guest count number as the term name (is that right?). All you would need to do is change from displaying the term_id to the term name.

Comment: I'm using admin column plug-in to manage the columns, I've tryed a lot of combinations but no way to see the number of guests (before with the combination "custom taxonomy" and "ospiti" i could see the number of  guests, maybe you know this plug in and the right selection?

Comment: Hi @Andrea Sacconi. I updated my answer. Now, the **term name** will be saved to post meta and not **term_id**. Term name should appear on your Admin Edit Post List Page. I'm assuming the term name has the value you want to see on the screen. You can see where the recent changes are using the little arrow to the left of the word **edited** on the [Timeline](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/415714/timeline) page. This change is significant because it will make all current values in Post Meta for the field `tax_input[numero_ospiti]` **invalid**. It could be a "breaking" change.

Comment: Hi @kofeigen , I think there is an error at this line: 'taxonomy' => 'whoa_activity' in Save value(s) from the form to database, shouldnt it be 'taxonomy' => 'numero_ospiti'?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The error appears once in `custom_meta_box_markup` and once in `save_custom_meta_box`. I was using another value while testing. I just updated my answer. Did you see both errors? Did it work for you after the corrections?

Comment: ok, bingo! If you want pls let me know if you have a profile or contact page somewhere, I suppose you are a professional developer, I could need other functions...

Comment: I have found another this time posive collateral effect: the data of latitude and longitude stay sticky in the little fields so that I can hide the big ones [link] (https://ibb.co/dcsChrq), I suppose it works this way for all the custom boxes connected with the default wordpress functions fields, it would be great

Comment: Great to see it finally works, and your latitude and longitude display as you like. I don't use GitHub often. But, you should be able to message me there. I use the same user name. Maybe you can help me with Admin Columns Plugin! :-)

Comment: Can I do use the same schema for every new taxonomy? I'm doing the same for the number of bedrooms but it doesnt work, I just changed the name: function register_tax_input_camere() {
    \register_meta(
        'post',
        'tax_input[numero_camere]', and so on, I replaced numero_ospiti with numero_camere, I invented a new name for id custom meta box    'meta-box-camere',          // Unique ID.

Comment: Sorry. I do not know how the plugins work. I cannot provide an answer. I guess you are [using this](https://docs.admincolumns.com/article/59-custom-field-columns)? Your **N.ospiti** taxonomy selector displays `numero_ospiti` taxonomy term names. But, the selected name is stored as a Post Custom Field (Post Meta). The AdminColumns plugin is reading the Post Meta (not taxonomy term name) for display in a column on the Admin Edit Post List Page. The plugin could be making an association between the taxonomy `numero_ospiti` and the post meta key `tax_input[numero_ospiti]`. (But, I don't know.)

Comment: In [your image](https://ibb.co/55KZ4ZY), the red text that says *VALUE OF TAXONOMY "numero_ospiti" IS NOT SHOWN*, could actually say *VALUE OF POST META KEY "tax_input[numero_ospiti]" IS NOT SHOWN*. Maybe if you provide an image of your AdminColumns configuration page where **numero_ospiti** is configured I might be able to understand better what AdminColumns is doing.

Comment: hi ,Admin column is working fine and I have understood the meta data I have to call, I have to select "custom field" and then select tax_imput[numero_ospiti]. What I cant do now is make a double of your code for another similar taxonomy. I tryed to change the name of the taxonomy and ID of the meta box, maybe should I change something else? Sorry for stalking you, you have already done a lot :)

Comment: probably I should understand the relation between "ospiti" and "numero_ospiti" in this part of your code  function register_tax_input_ospiti() {
    \register_meta(
        'post',
        'tax_input[numero_ospiti]',